# Using <%=[variable]=> syntax with htmlWebpackPlugin AND html-loader

Tags: javascript, webpack

Using Webpack 4 and it's HtmlWebpackPlugin and html-loader together, I'm trying to:

1. Load other html files into *index.html* from a directory
2. Load variables into *index.html* from htmlWebpackPlugin

However, this doesn't work when html-loader is present in *webpack.config.js*.
If I could use the same syntax that would be preferred, but I already tried using `${ }` for the title tag but i get an build error, `htmlWebpackPlugin undefined`.

### index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title> <!-- this doesn't work -->
   <!-- <title>${htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title}</title>        //also doesn't work -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>${require("./path/to/other.html")}</section> <!-- this works fine -->
    </body>
</html>
```

### webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './src',
    port: 4200,
    open: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      hash: true,
      template: './src/index.html'},
      title: 'Index Page')
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: /src/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(html)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'html-loader',
          options: {
            attrs:[':data-src'],
            minimize: false,
            conservativeCollapse: false,
            interpolate: true
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'style-loader' },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
}
```

Comment: (from this issue on github)[https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/593], jantimon stated that `the html-loader does not allow to use template variables.` Which answers why it's not working. But, Is there another way to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

It can be achieved by stacking up the following loaders in this sequence:

```
{
  test: /\.html$/,
  use: [{
    loader: 'ejs-loader'
  }, {
    loader: 'extract-loader'
  }, {
    loader: 'html-loader',
    options: {
      interpolate: true
  }
}
```

`html-loader` kicks in first replacing interpolated fragments, then we need to extract resulting HTML - that's why we use `extract-loader` and then `ejs-loader` can then replace `ejs` fragments and it does see `htmlWebpackPlugin` variables.

Comment: do I need to install these loaders

Comment: Html loader doesn't have an interpolate option

Comment: @Tofandel [It used to have it](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#100-2020-03-19:~:text=option%20was%20removed) Now you are your own

Comment: There is a workaround for HTML partials: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader/issues/291#issuecomment-721909576

Answer (score 2):

Just running into this issue today, found a solution and this page is still open in my browser.

Another method for solving this issue is by renaming the template file as `.ejs`, so rename `index.html` as `index.html.ejs`.

Then the config file should be:

```
   plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
       {
         hash: true,
         template: './src/index.html.ejs' // rename the file accordingly
       },
       title: 'Index Page')
  ],
```

This way html-webpack-plugin will process the ejs first as it actually a fallback loader for ejs. and html-loader will run after html-webpack-plugin producing html.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a closing curly bracket in the wrong place.

```
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    hash: true,
    template: './src/index.html'},
    title: 'Index Page')
],
```

Try to do it like this:

```
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    hash: true,
    template: './src/index.html',
    title: 'Index Page'
  })
],
```